# cURL_init() inside Foreach or outside Foreach() - Which is better?

Tags: php, curl

I have a CronJob that send cURL requests and I am thinking that what is the better approach to to this... I mean both works but *which is more efficient and faster?*

I have seen similar questions on SO but were not helpful

```
foreach(){
 $curl = curl_init();
 // cURL request
 $curl_close($curl);
}
```

OR

```
$curl_init($curl);
  foreach(){
     // cURL request
  }
$curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Call a function just once is always more performant and faster then call it n times.

Comment: The second one. You can edit the options and run with another URL if you wish. There's no reason to initialize it N times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, outside the loop. If you are calling any function once outside the loop, it will reduce number of function calls & therefore will improve performance.

So, call `curl_init` & set fixed options once outside the loop & set other dynamic options inside loop.